# The built-in WooCommerce importer won´t let me import products from a CSV file

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, import

I´m trying to import a CSV file to WooCommerce, I'm using the very same file resulted from an export, but it keeps telling me that for security reasons, the type of file I'm using can´t be used.

What could I be missing here

Rafael

Answer (score 0):

It was due to the fact that I was using HTML code to show a table of values in the description field